# Exception continuation doesn't work with completion continuation

Tags: .net, exception, task-parallel-library, continuations

I have this simple TPL code:

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw null; })
    .ContinueWith((ant) => { Console.WriteLine("Success"); }, 
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
    .ContinueWith((ant) => { Console.WriteLine("Error"); }, 
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
t.Wait();
```

I get an unhandled exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
...
```

If i put `t.Wait()` in a `try-catch`, the exception is caught there and i know it defies the whole point of using the exception continuation. Now, if i remove the completion continuation, the exception thrown by the task is handled in the exception continuation and i don't get the above exception. Can someone throw some light on whats happening?
I am using VS2010 SP1 with .NET 4.0

Comment: You planned to have 3 tasks to be executed in sequence. The first "throw null" task ends with `AggregateException`, and therefore the second "Success" task doesn't get started at all. Not to mentioned the third one "Error".

Comment: @JiajiWu, I have planned two tasks to be executed in a sequence - only one of the continuations is supposed to run after the parent task is done. It is obvious that the completion continuation will not run because of the exception thrown. But i don't understand why you say the exception continuation doesn't run?

Comment: `a.ContinueWith(b, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion).ContinueWith(c, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)` means "execute a; if a completes successfully, execute b; if b fails, execute c.". Sounds like what you intended to do is "execute a; if a completes successfully, execute b; otherwise (if a fails), execute c.". Then you should go with **svick**'s solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContinueWith()` doesn't return the original `Task`, it returns a `Task` representing the continuation. And in your case that continuation is canceled, because the original `Task` didn't run to completion. And because the second `Task` wasn't faulted, your third `Task` was canceled too, which is why you're getting `TaskCanceledException` wrapped inside `AggregateException`.

What you can do instead is to have one continuation, which does both actions. Something like:

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw null; })
    .ContinueWith(
        ant =>
        {
            if (ant.IsFaulted)
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
        });
```

If you do something like this often, you could create an extension method for this (plus probably a generic version for `Task<T>` with `Action<T>` as `onSuccess`):

```
public static Task ContinueWith(
    this Task task, Action onSuccess, Action<AggregateException> onError)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(
        ant =>
        {
            if (ant.IsFaulted)
                onError(task.Exception);
            else
                onSuccess();
        });
}
```

Usage:

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw null; })
    .ContinueWith(
        () => { Console.WriteLine("Success"); },
        ex => { Console.WriteLine("Error"); });
t.Wait();
```

Also, this assumes you know your original `Task` won't be canceled. If that's not the case, that's one more case you need to handle.